# openssh tty perms

Tags: gdb, openssh

With each and every ssh connection, there is an associated pseudo terminal set up like `/dev/ttyp1 /dev/ttyp2` etc.

In openssh in some code path, /dev/ttyp2  permissions are changed from `crw-rw-rw-` (default) to `crwx-w----` (after connection setup).

Is there any way I can see which code section does this in openssh?
May be with gdb debugger, is there any way I can 'watch' on a particular file permissions.

In some function in openssh, with `session *s` as argument, `s->tty` is set to `/dev/ttyp2` and by that time perms does not have `'x'` execution bit set. 
But after connection is setup completely, /dev/ttyp2 gets 'x' bit set.

I tried watching on address of `s->tty` variable but that does not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a function pty_setowner() in openssh/sshpty.c which actually does a chmod on tty device allocated for a session.

The problem that I faced was chmod is failing on tty dev file and tty dev file is not getting execution permission and thus there was no log printed on my terminal.

Thanks any ways.